# 2 Values search in Multidimensional array

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i am writing a very basic Windows form application in C# and needs to verify credentials with multidimensional array in simplest way possible

```
string[,] credentials;
credentials = new string[,] { {"name1", "pass"}, {"name2", "pass2"} };
```

i want my textbox1 and textbox2 to verify with credentials

```
for (int i = 0; i < credentials.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < credentials.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text && textBox2.Text == credentials[i,j])
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
    string[,] credentials = new string[,] { {"name1","pass" },{"name2","pass2" },{"name3","pass3" } };

    for (int i = 0; i < credentials.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if(textBox1.Text == credentials[i,0] && textBox2.Text == credentials[i,1]) {
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
            break;
        }
    }
```

You don't need to use two loops.

Here's a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4BKMgk).

Answer (score 0):

when u want to make it very simple i would use a Dictionary otherwise use a Database.

```
Dictionary<string, string> users = Enumerable.Range(0, credentials.GetLength(0)).ToDictionary(i => credentials[i, 0], i => credentials[i, 1]);

if(users[textBox1.Text] != null && users[textBox1.Text] == textBox2.Text){
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Why downvote ? Write a comment why my answer is bad.

Comment: "verify credentials with multidimensional array in simplest way possible" your answer does not do what was asked I suppose. On top of that if `users[textBox1.Text]` returns null and compares it against a string it'll go on fire.

Comment: Ok i edited it now it works with a multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code so it uses only one loop:

```
var credentials = new [,] { {"name1", "pass"}, {"name2", "pass2"} };

for (int i = 0; i < credentials.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == credentials[i, 0] && textBox2.Text == credentials[i, 1])
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
        break;
    }
}
```

I'd also add a break after you found a match, since you do not need to validate the remaining credentials.

---

If you're open for some improvements, I suggest to use a tuple array/list.

Add this at the beginning of the .cs file:

```
// Needed to make .Any() work
using System.Linq;
```

In your code:

```
// Credentials has type (string, string)[]
var credentials = new (string name, string pass)[] { ("name1", "pass1"), ("name2", "pass2") };
if (credentials.Any(c => textBox1.Text == c.name && textBox2.Text == c.pass))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
```

If you use C# 7.3, you can even write:

```
credentials.Any(c => c == (textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text))
```